# UITapGestureRecognizer tap on self.view but ignore subviews

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I need to implement a feature that will invoke some code when I double tap on the self.view (view of `UIViewController`). But the problem that I have other UI object on this view and I don't want to attach any recognizer object to all of them. I found this method below how to make gesture on my view and I know how it works. Right now I am in front of handicap which way to choose for create this recognizer ignoring subview. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried setting cancelsTouchesInView to NO on the recognizer? so [doubleTap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You should adopt the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol inside the `self` object and call the below method for checking the view. Inside this method, check your view against `touch.view` and return the appropriate bool (Yes/No). Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:yourSubView]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Edit: Please, also check @Ian's answer!

**Swift 5**

```swift
// MARK: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate methods, You need to set the delegate of the recognizer
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
     if touch.view?.isDescendant(of: tableView) == true {
        return false
     }
     return true
}
```

Comment: one more question I have few buttons on my view that have to work. how can I set some priority for them?

Comment: if your buttons have their own gesture recognizers (likely), dig into their internals and grab them, and read the docs on `-[UIGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:]` but it might work without mod'ing them

Comment: If your `if` test fails, your implementation fails to return a BOOL; for proper style return YES after an if block (using `{ }`) or in an `else` branch. Thanks, though, saved me a bit of reading.

Comment: A view is a descendant of itself so this doesn't work... (the overall approach is ok though, see other answer)

Comment: why not just `return ![touch.view isDescendantOfView:yourSubView]`

Answer (score 130):

Another approach is to just compare if the view of the touch is the gestures view, because descendants won't pass the condition. A nice, simple one-liner:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return touch.view == gestureRecognizer.view
}
```

Comment: This is working better for me than the accepted answer. Much more concise.

Comment: @Ian this method is not invoked when tapping on the view.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't even work but this worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: @Prabu propably because gesture recognizer's delegate must be set before

Comment: It the concerned subview has a child view, that child view's isUserInteractionEnabled property should be set false. Otherwise tapping on the child view wont let the subview recognize touch.

Answer (score 24):

And for the Swift variant:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view.isDescendantOfView(yourSubView){
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Good to know, `isDescendantOfView` returns a `Boolean` value indicating whether the receiver is a subview of a given view or identical to that view.

Comment: Don't forget to set the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in your class !

Comment: Instead of doing that if statement, can't you just return this?

return !touch.view.isDescendant(of: gestureRecognizer.view)

Also, new syntax in swift 3 ^^

Answer (score 18):

With Swift 5 and iOS 12, `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` has a method called [`gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624214-gesturerecognizer). `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:)` has the following declaration:

> Ask the delegate if a gesture recognizer should receive an object representing a touch.

```
optional func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool
```

---

The complete code below shows a possible implementation for `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:)`. With this code, a tap on a subview of the `ViewController`'s view (including `imageView`) won't trigger the `printHello(_:)` method.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(printHello))
        tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icon")!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
        view.addSubview(imageView)

        // ⚠️ Enable user interaction for imageView so that it can participate to touch events.
        // Otherwise, taps on imageView will be forwarded to its superview and managed by it.
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        // Prevent subviews of a specific view to send touch events to the view's gesture recognizers.
        if let touchedView = touch.view, let gestureView = gestureRecognizer.view, touchedView.isDescendant(of: gestureView), touchedView !== gestureView {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    @objc func printHello(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Hello")
    }

}
```

---

An alternative implementation of `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:)` can be:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return gestureRecognizer.view === touch.view
}
```

Note however that this alternative code does not check if `touch.view` is a subview of `gestureRecognizer.view`.

Answer (score 10):

Complete swift solution (delegate must be implemented AND set for recognizer(s) ):

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onBaseTapOnly))
        doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        doubleTapRecognizer.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if touch.view.isDescendantOfView(self.view){
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func onBaseTapOnly(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .Ended {
            //react to tap
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Variant using CGPoint you touch (SWIFT 4.0)**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

// Get the location in CGPoint
    let location = touch.location(in: nil)

// Check if location is inside the view to avoid
    if viewToAvoid.frame.contains(location) {
        return false
    }

    return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Clear Swift way**

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return touch.view == self.view
}
```

Comment: Never gets called in iOS 13, at least with swipeGestureRecognizer.

Comment: How is this different to Ian's answer?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the [gestureRecognizer API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624214-gesturerecognizer) has changed to:

gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:)

Take particular note of the underscore (skip) indicator for the first parameter's external label.

Using many of the examples provided above, I was not receiving the event. Below is a an example that works for current versions of Swift (3+).

```
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    var shouldReceive = false
    if let clickedView = touch.view {
        if clickedView == self.view {
            shouldReceive = true;
        }
    }
    return shouldReceive
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Plus the above solutions, do not forget to check `User Interaction Enabled` of your sub-view.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had to prevent the gesture on the child view. The only thing that worked is to allow and keep the first view and prevent gesture in all the next views:

```
   var gestureView: UIView? = nil

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if (gestureView == nil || gestureView == touch.view){
            gestureView = touch.view
            return true
        }
        return false
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4:**

`touch.view` is now an optional, so based on @Antoine's answer:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if let touchedView = touch.view, touchedView.isDescendant(of: deductibleBackgroundView) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your 'double-tap recogniser' to conflict with your buttons and/or other controls, you can set `self` as `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and implement:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool
{
    return !(touch.view is UIControl)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be found with the [`hitTest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest) function, which

> Returns the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy
> (including itself) that contains a specified point.

By this way defining the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` is not necessary:

```
@objc func tapFunction (_ recognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let viewTouched = recognizer.view?.hitTest(recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view), with: nil) {
        if viewTouched == self.parentView {
            //the parent view is tapped!
        }
    }
}
```