# How to detect UITapGestureRecognizer 's clicked view?

Tags: ios, xcode5, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

in order to close keyboard when clicked anywhere else from `UITextField`.

However in my view, I have UITableView , and I have to detect when click on the rows of UITableView.
Because of `UITapGestureRecognizer` my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function is not called. Is there any way to detect whether the clicked object is UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get thouch event of Gesture from

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

you detect touch of gesture so do logically like bellow:

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UITextFiled class]])
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {

     // here is remove keyBoard code
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the answer above couldn't solve your problem, try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814697/uitapgesturerecognizer-tap-on-self-view-but-ignore-subviews

Answer (score 0):

Implement this delegate method `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`, check and cancel your gesture callback which happen on tableview cell(row) and trigger tableview's delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES

}
```

Comment: This would show only the main view but not it's subviews. Actually this is the view that was registered to the gesture.