# Swift: userInteractionEnabled for subviews in spinning wheel concept

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicontrol

I am trying spinning wheel concept in iOS. My base tutorial is [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit)

UIControl is core here. Superview's `userinteraction` was disabled always.

So how to enable `userinteraction` for its subviews alone?

[image]

I have added `UITapGestureRecognizer` to SmallRoundViews. Gesture is not working.

If I change superview's userinteraction to enable, gesture is working. But, its not spinning.

If I change superview's userinteraction to disable, spinning is working. But gesture is not working.

I need everything to be done. Can you guide me?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I can think of at least one reason for this to be impossible: Since interactions are propagated from the parent to its children it is likely that the parent does not delegate anything if interaction is disabled, period. Pseudo: `if userInteractionDisabled return else delegateToChildren()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38217199/1979882

Comment: No. Everything is not working. Kindly do needful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code is working for,

If I change superview's `userinteraction` to `true`, both `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `spinning` is working..

Override `UITouch` method in `UIControl` subclass.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch : UITouch = touches.first!
        self.beginTracking(touch, with: event)
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch : UITouch = touches.first!
        self.continueTracking(touch, with: event)
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch : UITouch = touches.first!
        self.endTracking(touch, with: event)

}
```