# UIGesturerecognizer is not working on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

When I am tapping on UIView but Gesture is not working.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        viewForSHadow.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        viewForSHadow.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


func handleTap(_sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("---------View Tapped--------")
        viewForSHadow.isHidden = true
        viewForAlert.isHidden = true
    }
```

I just want to perform this action on UIView tap.

Comment: how many  times you pressed the gesture

Comment: do you have an UIImageCiew on top of the view or something that can consume the  gesture?

Comment: Where have you added viewForSHadow and what are the constraints you've added?

Comment: It is in main view and showing - hiding it.

Comment: once you will tap, your view will hide it's seems in your code. so your tap work only first time

Comment: @Coding once try to put code in viewWillAppear() and check, if not working  share details for viewForSHadow how you initialised it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check in the **debug view hierarchy** if anything with **alpha = 0** is overlapping your **viewForSHadow**.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement as follows:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_sender:)))
        viewForSHadow.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        viewForSHadow.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("---------View Tapped--------")
        viewForSHadow.isHidden = true
        viewForAlert.isHidden = true
    }
...

}
```

Comment: what is the use of `delegate` here and are you seen the code this once you pressed the gesture user hide the `viewForSHadow.isHidden = true`

Comment: the delegate is not needed here at all!

Comment: Yes, delegate is not required. @Anbu.Karthik I have just used Coding's code to make tap gesture working.

Comment: @BhavikModi - but if user clicked the view he hidden the own view

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik We don't know what exactly Coding wants :) You can ask him directly.

Comment: What you have tried and what is not working? I have already tested this and working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is more than enough to have working UIGestureRecognizer, you should check some other stuff like, is there something else that can consume the user interaction. And also to check if you use

`isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

to some parent view of viewForSHadow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention `numberOfTapsRequired` property of the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture(_sender:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    viewForSHadow.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    viewForSHadow.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func handleTapGesture(_sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("---------View Tapped--------")
    // Why are you hiding this view **viewForSHadow**
    viewForSHadow.isHidden = true
    viewForAlert.isHidden = true
}
```

Also, make sure you are not doing `viewForSHadow.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` anywhere in the code.

Comment: sorry, not agree with you, numberOfTapRequired have default value 1, this is the reason why this can't be the problem. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer/1623581-numberoftapsrequired

Comment: Can you check if you are not doing ```viewForSHadow.isUserInteractionEnabled = false``` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you code doesn't compile. The `handleTap(_:)` signature must be like:

```
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("---------View Tapped--------")
}
```

Secondly, you need to first try with the minimal code in a separate project. And by minimal code I mean what you've added in the question.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var viewForSHadow: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        viewForSHadow.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("---------View Tapped--------")
    }
}
```

Try with just the above code and see if you can get it working. The above code is working well at my end without any `delegate` or `numberOfTaps`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss))
        tapRecognizer.delegate = self
        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return true
}

@objc func handleDismiss() {
        print("handleDismiss")
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814697/uitapgesturerecognizer-tap-on-self-view-but-ignore-subviews)

Don't forget to set the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in your class